# Yii2: Number format

Tags: php, yii2

I have defined a column in Database as float.
The column is being shown as number in the model.
I want to format the columnn in Gridview with two decimal places and couldn't find a way, how it can be done.

I have tried to use this code but getting the error like - Unknown format type: number

```
[
   'label' => 'Charges',
   'attribute' => 'category_charges',
   'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
   'format' => ['number',2] 
],
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The correct syntax of formatting decimal number is like below:

```
'format'=>['decimal',2]
```

So your code should be:

```
[
    'label' => 'Charges',
    'attribute' =>'category_charges',
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1'],
    'format'=>['decimal',2]
],
```

To be more familiar with `Yii2`'s formatting take a look at the official document:

**[Class yii\i18n\Formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html)**

Comment: Ali - Great it's perfect

Comment: What about Indian money format like 1,00,00,000.00 ?

Answer (score 10):

Set grid column like this

```
'columns' => [
        [
            'format' => 'Currency',
            'attribute' => 'amount',
        ],            
    ],
```

in main.php add under 'components':

```
'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\formatter',
        'thousandSeparator' => ',',
        'decimalSeparator' => '.',
        'currencyCode' => '$'
    ],
```

Comment: The question asked is about float, so I can't really upvote, but *I* was looking for currency and your answer let me figure how to display a ₹ next to my floats. So thanks, and keep rocking! :-)

Comment: how to remove decimal?